# How can i create a list of lists

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a list of offset vars and i need to put it in another list so
I can call it like

```
List<list<offset>> coords 
  coords[0][i] = points[i]
```

But it didnt work.

Any suggestion??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your lists before:

```
final size = points.size;
var coords = List<List<offset>>.generate(size,(i) => List<offset>.generate(size, (j) => 0));
coords[0][i]=points[i];
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. You re right, all i had to do is initialize it.